# how to send 2 parameters to method in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I have an AutoComplete control and I need to send a parameter plus the ValueChange method

```
<BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="searchProvedores"                                                     
    TValue="T200MmTerceros"                                                        
    TItem="T200MmTerceros"                                                        
    Value="conceptos.SelectedProveedor"                                                        
    ValueChanged="SelectedProveedorChanged"                                                        
    ValueExpression="@(() => conceptos.SelectedProveedor,conceptos.f5962_rowid)"                                                        
    Placeholder="Escribe 4 caracteres para buscar..." MinimumLength="4">
      <SelectedTemplate Context="T200MmTerceros">@T200MmTerceros.RazonSocial</SelectedTemplate>
      <ResultTemplate Context="T200MmTerceros">@T200MmTerceros.RazonSocial @T200MmTerceros.Id)</ResultTemplate>
</BlazoredTypeahead>                                             
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => conceptos.SelectedProveedor)" />
```

And:

```
private async Task\<IEnumerable\<T200MmTerceros\>\> searchProvedores(String searchText)
{

    model.SearchProveedores = searchText;
    var result = await new ProxyLogicaNegocio("", HCore.UrlSiesaApi).GetGestionViajesProvedoresListAsync(model);
    return result;

}

private async Task SelectedProveedorChanged(T200MmTerceros t200MmTerceros, int concepto )
{
    //SelectedProveedor = t200MmTerceros;
    
    model.RowidTerceroProv = t200MmTerceros.Rowid;
    model = await new ProxyLogicaNegocio("", HCore.UrlSiesaApi).GetGestionViajesSucursalesAsync(model);
   // Sucursales = model.SucursalViajes;
   data[0].SelectedProveedor = t200MmTerceros;
    data[0].SelectedSucursales = model.SucursalViajes; 

}`
```

but i get the following errors
-No overload for method 'TypeCheck' takes 2 arguments
-Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
-Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'

I need to be able to send another parameter that would allow me to know which item in the list to modify the value that was selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from this part:

```
ValueExpression="@(() => conceptos.SelectedProveedor,conceptos.f5962_rowid)"
```

I'm not sure what the rowid is supposed to be for but this should at least compile:

```
ValueExpression="@(() => conceptos.SelectedProveedor)"
```

Note that the `For` in `<ValidationMessage For="@(() => conceptos.SelectedProveedor)" />` also uses a ValueExpression.

Comment: What happens is I am iterating over a list, to create a number N of BlazoredTypeahead, each BlazoredTypeahead modifies another object, sending the ID would allow me to know which one was modified and which other control to affect

Comment: That desire does not change the definition of ValueExpression.

Comment: it is not possible to send another parameter to the method SelectedProveedorChanged?